# Pandas: Creating an index of unique values based off of two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic, data-science

I am in the process of refining my code for a project where I am creating shipping lanes. What I currently have is dataframe that is put together by the index values of c_match. Cool, great everything looks correct at first glance.

A shipping lane is a group of states with the same discount and min charge. My code returns states with the same discount. Most states that have the same discount also have the same min charge. However the outliers are states with the same discount and different min charges.

The goal: To create shipping lanes that have the same min charges and the same discount percentages.

My Idea: Create a logical operation that concats the state names who have identical rates and costs and also returns their rates and costs. States with different costs for the same rate still need to be accounted for.

Desired Output:

```
Shipping Lane                                 Rate  Cost
20_21_RDWY_Purple_AL_AR_KY_LA_MS_SC_TN_PE   50.80%  120
20_21_RDWY_Purple_AZ                        50.80%  155
20_21_RDWY_Purple_CA                        62.40%  145
20_21_RDWY_Purple_CO_ND_WY_MB_NF_PQ         62.40%  155
20_21_RDWY_Purple_CT_DE_MN_NE               50.00%  145
20_21_RDWY_Purple_DC_IA_KS_MD_MI_OH_OK_WI   49.00%  125
20_21_RDWY_Purple_FL                        48.30%  125
```

Current Code:

```
def remove_dups(input, output):
    input.sort()
    n_list = list(input for input, _ in itertools.groupby(input))
    output.append(n_list)


def get_matches_discount(state):
    state_groups = []
    state_rates = []
    state_cost = []
    final_format = []

    match = []
    c_match = []
   
    for i, x in enumerate(df_d[state]):
        #checks within the column for identical values then maps where the identical values are
        match1 = [j for j, y in enumerate(df_d[state].isin([x])) if y is True]
        match.append(match1)
        remove_dups(match, c_match)


    for list in c_match:

        for elements in list:
            r = elements[0]
            state_g = df_d.index[elements]
            state_groups.append(state_g)

            state_r = df_d[state][r]
            state_rates.append(state_r)
            print(state_rates)
            match_cost = df_m[state][r]
            state_cost.append(match_cost)

    for i in state_groups:
        delimiter = "_"

        join_str = delimiter.join(i)

        j_str = "20_21_RDWY_Purple_" + join_str

        final_format.append(j_str)

    master_frame = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Shipping Lane': final_format,
         'Rate': state_rates,
         'Cost': state_cost,
         }
    )
    print(master_frame)
    return master_frame


m_col_names = ['AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA',
               'MA', 'MD', 'ME', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NV', 'NY', 'OH',
               'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY', 'AB', 'BC',
               'MB', 'NB', 'NF', 'NS', 'ON', 'PE', 'PQ', 'SK']
# calls the function in a loop to process one column at a time
# creates the master data frame outside of the function calling for loop
master_dataframe0 = pd.DataFrame()
for state in m_col_names:
    temp_df = get_matches_discount(state)
    # Stores the function call as a variable
    master_dataframe0 = master_dataframe0.append(temp_df)
    # Creates an appended dataframe outside of the function
print(master_dataframe0)
master_dataframe0.to_excel("shipping_lanes_revised00.xlsx")
```

Sample input:

Minimum Charge Table

this is dataframe: df_m

```
State   AL     AR     AZ     CA       CO      CT     DC
AL  120.00  120.00  155.00  145.00  155.00  145.00  125.00
AR  120.00  120.00  155.00  155.00  145.00  155.00  145.00
AZ  155.00  155.00  120.00  120.00  125.00  185.00  185.00
CA  145.00  164.30  120.00  120.00  170.00  185.00  185.00
CO  155.00  145.00  125.00  145.00  120.00  155.00  155.00
CT  145.00  155.00  185.00  185.00  155.00  120.00  120.00
DC  125.00  155.00  185.00  185.00  155.00  120.00  185.00
DE  145.00  155.00  185.00  185.00  155.00  120.00  120.00
FL  125.00  145.00  145.00  185.00  145.00  155.00  145.00
GA  120.00  120.00  155.00  145.00  155.00  145.00  120.00
IA  125.00  125.00  155.00  145.00  125.00  155.00  145.00
ID  145.00  155.00  145.00  145.00  125.00  185.00  185.00
IL  120.00  120.00  155.00  145.00  145.00  125.00  125.00
IN  120.00  120.00  155.00  145.00  145.00  125.00  120.00
KS  125.00  120.00  155.00  155.00  120.00  155.00  145.00
KY  120.00  120.00  155.00  145.00  145.00  125.00  125.00
LA  120.00  120.00  155.00  145.00  155.00  155.00  155.00
MA  155.00  155.00  185.00  185.00  145.00  120.00  120.00
MD  125.00  145.00  185.00  185.00  155.00  120.00  120.00
ME  155.00  155.00  185.00  185.00  145.00  120.00  125.00
MI  125.00  125.00  145.00  145.00  155.00  125.00  120.00
MN  145.00  125.00  155.00  145.00  145.00  155.00  145.00
MO  120.00  120.00  155.00  155.00  125.00  145.00  145.00
MS  120.00  120.00  155.00  155.00  145.00  155.00  145.00
MT  145.00  155.00  155.00  155.00  125.00  185.00  185.00
NC  120.00  125.00  145.00  185.00  155.00  125.00  120.00
ND  155.00  155.00  145.00  145.00  155.00  155.00  155.00
NE  145.00  125.00  155.00  155.00  120.00  155.00  155.00
NH  155.00  155.00  185.00  185.00  145.00  120.00  120.00
NJ  145.00  155.00  185.00  185.00  155.00  120.00  120.00
NM  155.00  125.00  120.00  145.00  120.00  145.00  145.00
NV  145.00  155.00  120.00  120.00  145.00  185.00  185.00
NY  145.00  145.00  185.00  185.00  155.00  120.00  120.00
OH  125.00  125.00  145.00  145.00  155.00  120.00  120.00
OK  125.00  120.00  145.00  155.00  120.00  155.00  155.00
OR  185.00  145.00  155.00  125.00  155.00  185.00  185.00
PA  145.00  145.00  185.00  185.00  155.00  120.00  120.00
RI  155.00  155.00  185.00  185.00  145.00  120.00  120.00
SC  120.00  120.00  145.00  185.00  155.00  125.00  120.00
SD  155.00  145.00  155.00  155.00  120.00  155.00  145.00
TN  120.00  120.00  155.00  145.00  155.00  145.00  125.00
TX  125.00  120.00  145.00  155.00  125.00  145.00  155.00
UT  170.00  164.30  132.50  132.50  127.20  145.00  145.00
VA  120.00  145.00  145.00  185.00  155.00  120.00  120.00
```

Discount Table

this is datatframe: df_d

```
State   AL      AR      AZ      CA      CO     CT     DC
    AL  50.80%  44.10%  54.30%  73.10%  53.90%  50.00%  49.00%
    AR  50.80%  50.80%  53.90%  65.70%  50.00%  53.90%  50.00%
    AZ  56.70%  55.80%  50.80%  54.10%  49.60%  59.50%  64.40%
    CA  62.40%  61.00%  54.30%  61.40%  43.00%  52.30%  54.30%
    CO  54.30%  67.10%  49.00%  65.70%  50.80%  54.30%  54.30%
    CT  50.00%  53.90%  64.40%  72.50%  54.30%  50.80%  50.80%
    DC  49.00%  53.90%  64.40%  64.40%  54.30%  50.80%  64.40%
    DE  50.00%  53.90%  64.40%  64.40%  54.30%  50.80%  50.80%
    FL  48.30%  35.00%  55.50%  55.50%  55.10%  66.40%  62.30%
    GA  67.90%  44.10%  71.00%  64.60%  56.00%  50.00%  44.10%
    IA  49.00%  49.00%  54.30%  61.80%  49.00%  53.90%  50.00%
    ID  61.80%  54.30%  50.00%  75.90%  49.00%  64.40%  64.40%
    IL  44.10%  44.10%  54.30%  64.00%  50.00%  49.00%  49.00%
    IN  44.10%  1.60%   11.70%  26.10%  -0.70%  49.00%  44.10%
    KS  49.00%  63.40%  61.00%  67.70%  72.50%  72.20%  50.00%
    KY  50.80%  44.10%  54.30%  61.50%  50.00%  49.00%  49.00%
    LA  50.80%  44.10%  54.30%  61.80%  53.90%  54.30%  53.90%
    MA  63.50%  53.90%  67.70%  63.90%  53.00%  63.50%  44.10%
    MD  49.00%  50.00%  64.40%  73.80%  54.30%  50.80%  50.80%
    ME  53.90%  54.30%  64.40%  64.40%  61.80%  50.80%  49.00%
    MI  49.00%  49.00%  61.80%  55.10%  53.90%  49.00%  44.10%
    MN  50.00%  49.00%  54.30%  61.80%  50.00%  53.90%  50.00%
    MO  44.10%  50.80%  53.90%  56.10%  49.00%  50.00%  50.00%
    MS  50.80%  50.80%  54.30%  63.90%  50.00%  53.90%  50.00%
    MT  61.80%  54.30%  53.90%  75.80%  49.00%  64.40%  64.40%
    NC  44.10%  59.20%  53.50%  58.60%  57.90%  42.90%  69.60%
    ND  54.30%  53.90%  61.80%  61.80%  54.30%  53.90%  53.90%
    NE  50.00%  49.00%  54.30%  54.30%  44.10%  53.90%  53.90%
    NH  53.90%  54.30%  64.40%  64.40%  61.80%  50.80%  44.10%
    NJ  50.50%  51.50%  70.50%  66.20%  59.70%  67.10%  50.80%
    NM  53.90%  49.00%  44.10%  68.20%  44.10%  61.80%  61.80%
    NV  61.80%  54.30%  52.70%  73.50%  50.00%  64.40%  64.40%
    NY  61.10%  69.00%  65.50%  68.90%  63.00%  68.40%  50.80%
    OH  49.00%  49.00%  68.50%  71.50%  72.30%  60.70%  44.10%
    OK  49.00%  50.80%  50.00%  54.30%  44.10%  54.30%  54.30%
    OR  64.40%  61.80%  53.90%  64.00%  53.90%  64.40%  64.40%
    PA  47.20%  57.00%  33.70%  51.90%  45.50%  50.80%  50.80%
    RI  53.90%  54.30%  64.40%  64.40%  61.80%  50.80%  44.10%
    SC  50.80%  44.10%  61.80%  58.70%  54.30%  49.00%  44.10%
    SD  53.90%  50.00%  54.30%  54.30%  44.10%  54.30%  61.80%
    TN  50.80%  50.80%  52.50%  62.60%  61.30%  53.30%  49.00%
    TX  56.60%  46.00%  51.40%  58.30%  53.20%  63.10%  65.10%
    UT  45.00%  60.60%  73.50%  73.50%  70.30%  44.40%  61.90%
    VA  57.90%  50.00%  61.80%  72.10%  54.30%  44.10%  50.80%
```

Current Output:

```
                                                                      Shipping Lane     Rate   Cost
0                                             20_21_RDWY_Purple_AL_AR_KY_LA_MS_SC_TN_PE   50.80%  120.0
1                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_AZ   56.70%  155.0
2                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_CA   62.40%  145.0
3                                                   20_21_RDWY_Purple_CO_ND_WY_MB_NF_PQ   54.30%  155.0
4                                                         20_21_RDWY_Purple_CT_DE_MN_NE   50.00%  145.0
5                                             20_21_RDWY_Purple_DC_IA_KS_MD_MI_OH_OK_WI   49.00%  125.0
6                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_FL   48.30%  125.0
7                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_GA   67.90%  120.0
8                                                      20_21_RDWY_Purple_ID_MT_NV_AB_SK   61.80%  145.0
9                                                      20_21_RDWY_Purple_IL_IN_MO_NC_WV   44.10%  120.0
10                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_MA   63.50%  155.0
11                                            20_21_RDWY_Purple_ME_NH_NM_RI_SD_VT_NB_NS   53.90%  155.0
12                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_NJ   50.50%  145.0
13                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_NY   61.10%  145.0
14                                                           20_21_RDWY_Purple_OR_WA_BC   64.40%  185.0
15                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_PA   47.20%  145.0
16                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_TX   56.60%  125.0
17                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_UT   45.00%  170.0
18                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_VA   57.90%  120.0
19                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_ON   37.30%  145.0
0                                                   20_21_RDWY_Purple_AL_GA_IL_KY_LA_SC   44.10%  120.0
1                                          20_21_RDWY_Purple_AR_MO_MS_OK_TN_NB_NF_NS_PE   50.80%  120.0
2                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_AZ   55.80%  155.0
3                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_CA   61.00%  164.3
4                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_CO   67.10%  145.0
5                                                   20_21_RDWY_Purple_CT_DC_DE_MA_ND_MB   53.90%  155.0
6                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_FL   35.00%  145.0
7                                             20_21_RDWY_Purple_IA_MI_MN_NE_NM_OH_WI_WV   49.00%  125.0
8                                          20_21_RDWY_Purple_ID_ME_MT_NH_NV_RI_VT_PQ_SK   54.30%  155.0
9                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_IN    1.60%  120.0
10                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_KS   63.40%  120.0
11                                                        20_21_RDWY_Purple_MD_SD_VA_WY   50.00%  145.0
12                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_NC   59.20%  125.0
13                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_NJ   51.50%  155.0
14                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_NY   69.00%  145.0
15                                                           20_21_RDWY_Purple_OR_WA_AB   61.80%  145.0
16                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_PA   57.00%  145.0
17                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_TX   46.00%  120.0
18                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_UT   60.60%  164.3
19                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_BC   64.40%  185.0
20                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_ON   32.10%  145.0
0                              20_21_RDWY_Purple_AL_CA_IA_IL_KY_LA_MN_MS_NE_SD_WA_AB_BC   54.30%  155.0
1                                                         20_21_RDWY_Purple_AR_MO_MT_OR   53.90%  155.0
2                                                      20_21_RDWY_Purple_AZ_NB_NF_NS_PE   50.80%  120.0
3                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_CO   49.00%  125.0
4                                    20_21_RDWY_Purple_CT_DC_DE_MD_ME_NH_RI_VT_ON_PQ_SK   64.40%  185.0
5                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_FL   55.50%  145.0
6                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_GA   71.00%  155.0
7                                                            20_21_RDWY_Purple_ID_OK_WY   50.00%  145.0
8                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_IN   11.70%  155.0
9                                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_KS   61.00%  155.0
10                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_MA   67.70%  185.0
11                                                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_MI_ND_SC_VA_WV_MB   61.80%  145.0
12                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_NC   53.50%  145.0
13                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_NJ   70.50%  185.0
14                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_NM   44.10%  120.0
15                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_NV   52.70%  120.0
16                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_NY   65.50%  185.0
17                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_OH   68.50%  145.0
18                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_PA   33.70%  185.0
19                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_TN   52.50%  155.0
20                                                                 20_21_RDWY_Purple_TX   51.40%  145.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple rows for states but they are also on columns. It looks like you were just showing example output for the `AL` column though? You can merge two dataframes on `State` and then `.groupby` `Rate` and `Cost`. Then, return a joined string (with `.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x))`) of the states with the same rate and cost (since you grouped by them they will have same rate and cost):

```
master_dataframe0 = (pd.merge(df_d[['State', 'AL']], df_m[['State', 'AL']], how='inner', on='State')
                    .rename({'AL_x' : 'Rate', 'AL_y' : 'Cost'}, axis=1)
                    .groupby(['Rate', 'Cost'])['State'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x)).reset_index()
                    .sort_values('State'))
master_dataframe0 = master_dataframe0[['State', 'Rate', 'Cost']].assign(State='20_21_RDWY_Purple_' + master_dataframe0['State'])
master_dataframe0
Out[1]: 
                                     State    Rate   Cost
7   20_21_RDWY_Purple_AL_AR_KY_LA_MS_SC_TN  50.80%  120.0
11                    20_21_RDWY_Purple_AZ  56.70%  155.0
15                    20_21_RDWY_Purple_CA  62.40%  145.0
9                  20_21_RDWY_Purple_CO_ND  54.30%  155.0
5            20_21_RDWY_Purple_CT_DE_MN_NE  50.00%  145.0
4   20_21_RDWY_Purple_DC_IA_KS_MD_MI_OH_OK  49.00%  125.0
3                     20_21_RDWY_Purple_FL  48.30%  125.0
18                    20_21_RDWY_Purple_GA  67.90%  120.0
14              20_21_RDWY_Purple_ID_MT_NV  61.80%  145.0
0            20_21_RDWY_Purple_IL_IN_MO_NC  44.10%  120.0
16                    20_21_RDWY_Purple_MA  63.50%  155.0
8         20_21_RDWY_Purple_ME_NH_NM_RI_SD  53.90%  155.0
6                     20_21_RDWY_Purple_NJ  50.50%  145.0
13                    20_21_RDWY_Purple_NY  61.10%  145.0
17                    20_21_RDWY_Purple_OR  64.40%  185.0
2                     20_21_RDWY_Purple_PA  47.20%  145.0
10                    20_21_RDWY_Purple_TX  56.60%  125.0
1                     20_21_RDWY_Purple_UT  45.00%  170.0
12                    20_21_RDWY_Purple_VA  57.90%  120.0
```

Comment: How do you then rename every state and not just AL

Comment: @AdamZuckerman how would the output look like? 50 different column of rate and 50 different columns Cost? Or as rows and you can perhaps classify each one as  `AL - 0_21_RDWY_Purple_AL_AR_KY_LA_MS_SC_TN` , `CA - 20_21_RDWY_Purple_AZ`, `CA - 0_21_RDWY_Purple_AL_AR_KY_LA_MS_SC_TN` , `AL - 20_21_RDWY_Purple_AZ` You see what I mean by prefixing the state from the columns. Either way, I think it is best you create a new SO question that is an extension of this one with the desired output. You don't have to show all 50 states in column and on rows, but perhaps just a couple, so people get an idea.

Comment: The output looks great now ! I figured it out. Simple fix: .rename({state + '_x': 'Rate', state + '_y': 'Cost'}, axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

Using Erickson's help with the `.groupby` and lambda functions, we arrive at the correct solution:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

df_d = pd.read_excel(path,
                        sheet_name=0,
                        header=0,
                        index_col=False,
                        keep_default_na=True)
df_m = pd.read_excel(path2,
                       sheet_name=0,
                       header=0,
                       index_col=False,
                       keep_default_na=True)

m_col_names = ['AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA',
               'MA', 'MD', 'ME', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NV', 'NY', 'OH',
               'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY', 'AB', 'BC',
               'MB', 'NB', 'NF', 'NS', 'ON', 'PE', 'PQ', 'SK']

final_frame = pd.DataFrame()
for state in m_col_names:

    master_dataframe0 = (pd.merge(df_d[['State', state]], df_m[['State', state]], how='inner', on='State')
                         .rename({state + '_x': 'Rate', state + '_y': 'Cost'}, axis=1)
                         .groupby(['Rate', 'Cost'])['State'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x)).reset_index()
                         .sort_values('State'))
    master_dataframe0['Origin'] = state
    master_dataframe0 = master_dataframe0[['State', 'Rate', 'Cost', 'Origin']].assign(
        State='20_21_RDWY_Purple_' + master_dataframe0['State'])

    final_frame = final_frame.append(master_dataframe0)

    print(final_frame)
    final_frame.to_excel("w3llshipmeright.xlsx")
```

Correct Output:

[image: Final_Data_Frame_(:(:(:]